# Electron doesn't render any html after an select box

Tags: chromium, electron

I have a basic html form with Angular JS.

```
<div class="form-control" id="alarm">
    <select ng-model="vm.clock.alarm" ng-options="option.title for option in vm.alarms track by option.url"/>
</div>
```

This runs fine in a chrome browser window.  However, when I run this inside of an electron app, the select box renders and functions fine, but no html is rendered after it.  There are no javascript errors.  When I inspect the html, there is no html after the select element in the dom.  Why is electron not rendering the html just like a chrome browser?

I am using the latest version of electron, chrome, and 1.4.8 of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was with the select option and not having a closing `</select>` tag.  Must be a bug in electron or electron's chromium version.

```
<div class="form-control" id="alarm">
<select ng-model="vm.clock.alarm" ng-options="option.title for option in vm.alarms track by option.url">
</select>
</div>
```

works

Comment: I don't think its a bug, I think this is actually the correct way to define a select tag.

Comment: The select box is in good syntax though, in that is has an opening and closing tag.  To have no html spit out after good syntax is odd, especially since everything works fine in a chrome browser.